# Check if player is waiting

Tags: java

I have a question about a Runnable. I want to delay the execution of a command with 5 secs. I use the following class for that:

```
public class GLGCommandHandler implements CommandExecutor{

public GoodLifeGaming plugin;
public Thread animatie;
public ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

public GLGCommandHandler(GoodLifeGaming plugin)
{
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String args[])
{
    names.add(sender.getName());
    final CommandSender player = sender;
    ((Player)player).sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Teleportation will commence in " + ChatColor.RED + "5 seconds" + ChatColor.GOLD + ". Don't move.");
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((Player)player).sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Teleportation commencing...");
            ((Player)player).performCommand("mv spawn");
            names.remove(player.getName());
        }

    },100L);
    return true;
}


public boolean playerteleporting(Player player)
{
    if (names.contains(player.getName()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the player moves, I will get his name with a Listener (in another class) and I want to cancel the whole Runnable for that player. How can I do this? First I wanted to check if the player is actually waiting for a delay with the playerteleporting method but for some reason, this method always return false?!? It says the variable 'names' is empty, while I put the name of the sender in that arraylist.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post this on the Bukkit forums, but anyway:

You'll have to register a bunch of listeners and remove the player from `names` when an event happens that shouldn't (e.g. if the player moves). In the `run()` method check whether `names` still contains the player, and if it doesn't, cancel the teleport. You should also prevent the player from using the command again while the countdown is still in effect.

BTW: Using a `HashSet<String>` for `names` might be more efficient than an `ArrayList` (for small sizes [<= 3] an ArrayList is likely faster) and fits your needs better (since a Set can contain each element only once).

Comment: Okay thank you! I also found out about my other problem.
I used this:
GLGCommandHandler cls = new GLGCommandHandler(plugin); before this.plugin = plugin;